# VBScript to output that outputs an HTML table

Tags: html, vbscript

I am attempting to read a text file that contains rows and then output them in the form of columns in an html file.  I have no problem having this work when using WScript.echo to display it on the screen, but I am unable to get it to a table in an HTML file.  I am getting the following error when attempting to run the vbs file:  Type mismatch: 'OpenTextFile'.  Any guidance would be much appreciated

[image]

```
Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim OutputHTML : Set OutputHTML = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Istaley.RXDATA\Desktop\NewEmployeeTest\Part2_TableData.html")
Dim file : Set file = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Istaley.RXDATA\Desktop\NewEmployeeTest\Part2_data.txt", 1, True)
Dim fc : fc = file.ReadAll : file.close : Dim fcArray : fcArray = Split(fc, vbCrLf)
OutputHTML.WriteLine "<html>"
OutputHTML.Writeline "<body>"
OutputHTML.WriteLine "<table BORDER=1>"
Dim opArray() : ReDim opArray(0)
For Each row In fcArray
    Dim tmp: tmp = Split(row, "|")
    For ent=0 To UBound(tmp)
        If ent  > UBound(opArray) Then
            ReDim Preserve opArray(UBound(opArray)+1)
            opArray(ent) = Trim(tmp(ent))
        Else
            If Len(opArray(ent)) > 0 Then
                OutputHTML.WriteLine "<tr>"
                opArray(ent) = opArray(ent) & " " & Trim(tmp(ent))
                OutputHTML.WriteLine "</tr>"
            Else
                opArray(ent) = Trim(tmp(ent))
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
WScript.echo Join(opArray, vbCrLf)
OutputHTML.WriteLine "</table>"
OutputHTML.WriteLine "</body>"
OutputHTML.WriteLine "</html>"
OutputHTML.Write Join(opArray, vbCrLf) : OutputHTML.Close
```

Comment: Put the line `OutputHTML.Write Join(opArray, vbCrLf)` before the `OutputHTML.WriteLine "</table>"`. BTW where are `"<td>"` and `"</td>"` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line.. The first argument of [`OpenTextFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347(v=vs.60).aspx) takes a string, but you have passed it an Object. You've already opened the text file for writing using [`CreateTextFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265018(v=vs.60).aspx).

```
Set WriteOutput = fso.OpenTextFile(OutputHTML, 8, True)
```

Get rid of this line and change all remaining instances of `WriteOutput` to `OutputHTML`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the error is no more!  The html output is not being displayed in 3 columns or in a table.  There is a rectangle above 1 2 3 2 3 4 3 4 5 4 5 6 5 6 7.  I will update my code above to show you what I have and post a screen shot.  If I add WScript.echo, I am able to see my desired output, but I just can't get it into an html table

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old topic, but this might be useful to anyone looking to do the same, like I did.  It's a bit rushed, but I've added comments inline.  Bits have been taken from a number of locations, so it's not all my own work...

```
Function LoadFile(File)
    On Error Resume Next
    'Declaire all variables
    Dim fso,F,ReadText,strError
    Dim ReadArray
    Dim ReadHTMLOutput, ReadRowCount, ReadRowItem, ReadRowItemSplit, ReadElementCount, ReadElementItem
    'Create the object to read files
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Set the file to read and the format
    Set F = fso.OpenTextFile(File,1)
    'If there's a problem, say so...
    If Err.Number <> 0  Then
        strError = "<center><b><font color=Red>The file "& File &" dosen't exists !</font></b></center>"
        OutputTable.InnerHTML = strError
        Exit Function
    End If
    'Read the contents of the file into ReadText
    ReadText = F.ReadAll

    'Split the text based on Carriage return / Line feed
    ReadArray = Split(ReadText,vbCrLf)
    'fill the output variable with the HTML of the start of the table
    ReadHTMLOutput = "<table border=" & chr(34) & "2" & chr(34) & ">" & vbcrlf
    'starting at 0 until the last line in the array, run through each line
    For ReadRowCount=0 to UBound(ReadArray)
        'Take the whole row into it's own variable
        ReadRowItem = ReadArray(ReadRowCount)
        'Split the row (separated by commas) into an array
        ReadRowItemSplit = Split(ReadRowItem,",")
        'Add the HTML for the row of the table
        ReadHTMLOutput = ReadHTMLOutput & "<tr>" & vbcrlf
        'starting at 0 until the last entry of the row array, run through each element
        For ReadElementCount=0 to UBound(ReadRowItemSplit)
            'Read the element into a variable
            ReadElementItem = ReadRowItemSplit(ReadElementCount)
            'If the element is blank, put a space in (stops the cell being formatted empty)
            If ReadElementItem = "" Then ReadElementItem = "&nbsp;"
            'Add the HTML for the cell of the row of the table
            ReadHTMLOutput = ReadHTMLOutput & "<td>" & ReadElementItem & "</td>" & vbcrlf
        'Go to the next element in the row
        Next
        'Add the HTML for the end of the row of the table
        ReadHTMLOutput = ReadHTMLOutput & "</tr>" & vbcrlf
    'Go to the next row in the file
    Next
    'Add the HTML for the end of the table
    ReadHTMLOutput = ReadHTMLOutput & "</table>" & vbcrlf
    'Fill the DIV with the contents of the variable
    OutputTable.InnerHTML = ReadHTMLOutput
End Function
```

and in the HTML:

```
<div id="OutputTable"></div>
```

That way, the DIV is filled with the HTML from `ReadHTMLOutput`